# Вызов метода родительской модели из элемента коллекции в Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, ооп, laravel

Я создал промежуточный класс между моделями и, собственно, `Model`.

```
class Transaction extends BaseModel
abstract class BaseModel extends Model
```

В классе `BaseModel` я добавил метод `getClass()`

```
protected function getClass($short = false) {
        $namespace = get_called_class();

        if ($short) {
            $className = explode('\\', $namespace);
            $className = end($className);
        } else {
            $className = $namespace;
        }

        return $className;
    }
```

После чего получил объект модели `Transaction` из коллекции и пытаюсь вызвать `getClass()`

В итоге вываливается ошибка следующего характера:

> ErrorException in Builder.php line 2345:
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getClass()

Вопрос: почему при попытке вызвать метод модели я получаю ошибку билдера и как это исправить?

Comment: Вам же сказали, что вы пытаетесь вызвать метод `getClass` на другом классе. `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`

Comment: Спасибо, кэп. Я не могу понять - почему так получилось, что вместо объекта модели у меня билдер? Я ведь уже выполнил запрос и получил коллекцию моделей.

Comment: Код вызова в студию